# How can we set up .env in react native application?

Tags: react-native, environment-variables

How can we set up `.env` in react native application? How to do environment setup inside react-native.

Comment: in my case for `ios` i use `.plist` file and for `android` the `flavors`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use 'react-native-dotenv' package. Install it and add "react-native-dotenv" preset to your .babelrc file at the project root, like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "react-native-dotenv"]
}
```

Then create a .env file and add your properties there, may be like this:

```
YOUR_FIELD="value"
```

finally, you should be able to use it in your src files, like this:

```
import { YOUR_FIELD } from 'react-native-dotenv';
console.log(YOUR_FIELD) // prints "value"
```

if you run into an issue while using this package, then you can look for further clarification in their GitHub page, right here:
https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv

Hope this helps.

Comment: found this article explain to me more with screenshot: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-gracefully-use-environment-variables-in-a-react-native-app/

Comment: Heads up (maintainer here): make sure to move `react-native-dotenv` to `plugins` in `v2.x.x` and change `import { YOUR_FIELD } from 'react-native-dotenv';` to `import { YOUR_FIELD } from '@env';`

Comment: For those who are looking at this in 2022
babel.config.js should be
`module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  
  plugins: [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "blacklist": null,
      "whitelist": null,
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": false
  }
]
  ]
};
`
and import must be 
`import { YOUR_FIELD } from '@env';`

Answer (score 3):

In React Native CLI
First install https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv this package
Then Create **.env** file in your Route Folder of your project and set urls like this

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL='https://api/v1'
REACT_APP_BT_AUTHORIZATION='....vynf6nzv'
```

After this, Create **Config.js** file in Route Folder and import your URLS like this

```
import {REACT_APP_BASE_URL, REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL} from '@env';

export default {
  REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
  REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL,
};
```

To Use these URLS
You can simply import config file in any file you want and use it like this one
//Importing config file

```
import config from '../../../config';
```

//Using config file to set urls

```
**`${config.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/user_requests`**
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two options

1) If you are using a project with native code, you can use [`react-native-config`](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config). This gives you the added benefit of using your `.env` variables in your android and iOS project files.

2) If you are using expo, [`react-native-dotenv`](https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For those using **expo** in 2023, there are two options recommended by their docs - [docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/)

See more details in this answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/75417112/1550202](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75417112/1550202)