# react native sudden Unable to resolve module `fs` error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, fs

I got a sudden error that the module 'fs' is unable to resolve. But I have not used this module nor changed anything. My App suddenly returns this error while starting.

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `fs` from
>   `/Path/to/Project/node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js`: Module `fs`
>   does not exist in the Haste module map
>
> This might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 To resolve try
>   the following:
>
> 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
> 2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
> 3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
> 4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

I already tried the four steps to resolve, several times but nothing helped. 
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you import anything from module "fs" accidentally? Just do a global search first to verify that.

Comment: Did not find anything in my project with fs

Comment: This occurs because either you've accidentally imported something from Node.js file system which is not compatible since you are not running the app on node environment or you are using a module which does use node.js file system.

Comment: `yarn install` or `npm install`?

Comment: yarn or npm install does not help either

Comment: Sometimes VScode generate something like 'import { stat } from 'fs';  you know when you code. Check if you have any imports in the app with 'fs' module..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For me, the issue was that VSCode had inserted some imports at the top of one of my js files. Very odd.
These were the lines:

```
import { tsConstructorType } from '@babel/types';
import { logger } from 'handlebars';
```

Comment: Same! The line was: import {formatResultsErrors} from 'jest-message-util';

Comment: You saved my day! my line was import NodeEnvironment from 'jest-environment-node'; Don't have any idea how vscode added that, quite scary

Comment: Incredible. I spent half a day wondering why my application was stalling. Thank you!

Comment: Same thing with VSCode automatically importing this line:
```import { format } from 'prettier';```

Answer (score 6):

One of my node modules is depending on react-native-dotenv, but its code was using old import like `import {} from 'react-native-dotenv'`.
But latest version of dotenv is using `import {} from '@env'`.
Fixing this import in the module resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can fix these surprise errors by clearing your cache. Run `$ expo start --clear`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I was trying to use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) when I should have been using [one of these react-native specific packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090286/7272109). Check that all your installed packages are compatible with react native.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue. Visual Studio Code users, autocomplete will sometimes auto-import modules you have no need for at the top of your file without you noticing. Running `git diff` revealed the following lines I had no memory of every writing at the top of a file I'd worked on:

```
+import { clearConfigCache } from 'prettier';
+import { createIconSetFromFontello } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
```

How to avoid:

Run `git diff` and read every single line that follows. The offenders will usually turn up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing a module (a functional/class component from another file) in expo react native, be sure to mention "./" in the **assets** array of the **rnpm** object in the package.json file like this:

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./"
    ]
  }
```

Do not try to install "fs" module separately, it would give more errors.

Answer (score 0):

my auto-suggestion accidentally imported this in my file which caused the same problem.

```
import { status } from "express/lib/response";
```

I removed and it worked.
try to find something in import that should not be there like from backend imports.