# How to access environment variables located in .env - React Native

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, intercom, intercom-ios

I currently have `.env` file in which I am saving api keys and such (not actual keys in the example below):

```
API_URL=https://www.example.si/3000
IOS_API_KEY=738d7hfu3hffsjfsd
STRIPE_KEY=pk_fh843f483ff3f43f34
APP_ID=pk_fh843f483ff3f43f34
```

I need to access these keys in my `AppDelegate.m` file.

I've tried the following:

`NSString *AppID = @(getenv("APP_ID"));`

But it didn't work.I get an error :
`"***+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:] NULL cString"` .

I cannot use variable as `@"AppID"` where I want to pass it in. Any ideas on how to solve this issue would be helpful.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727891/how-to-reference-an-environment-variable-inside-obj-c-code

Comment: I ended up using a library for this react-native-config: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config and it works really well. It also has system in place to avoid delayed (state based) caching.

Comment: Even though using a library to solve miniature issues such as this is not the best practice (creates unnecessary dependencies), I've decided that it is a good solution for my case.

Comment: Why is the question not tagged as react native?

Comment: That's a valid point, I will update the post. Initially, because it is a Objective-C file and not a JS file but as you have pointed out, it's misleading. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a library for this, called **react-native-config**:

https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

and it works really well. It also has a system in place to avoid delayed (state based) caching so as soon as you save `.env` file there is no chance of remembering the previous state of `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"Process.env.{{variable_name}}"` to access the Environment Variable.

Comment: I was too fast to judge, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**For those using EXPO, there are two options as explained at [docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/)**

This is the option I chose for my project:

### Using the `extra` field

Setup your `app.config.js` with this:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'MyApp',
  version: '1.0.0',
  extra: {
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL,
  },
};
```

Then run `API_URL="https://production.example.com" npx expo start`.
If you're using Windows, you can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env to be able to set the variables like this.

Now you should be able to access your env variables:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const apiUrl = Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.apiUrl;
```